# In a Telegram chatting group, how to navigate to a particular date?

Tags: telegram-messenger

In a Telegram chatting group or chatting room, how to navigate to a particular date in the sequence of messages?

I sometimes read the last part of the messages in a group first, but eventually want to navigate back to the point/date where I visited the group the last time and would like to read from there on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the desktop app, you have the search icon at the top right, clicking on it will bring the search box on the left. There you will have a calendar icon at the right of the field and you can jump directly to a specific date.
[image: jump to date on telegram desktop]

On the Android app, go on the 3 dots menu on the top right, tap on search and the calendar icon will appear at the left of the field, which appears at the bottom of the screen
[image: jump to date on telegram android]